# Guest Additions in Virtualbox problem

Tags: 12.04, drivers

IN UBUNTU 12.04...
After installing Guest Additions, I restarted, then, I logged in. After logging in, all I see is a desktop with a invisible bar (top bar but invisible, I mean).
when I clicked RANDOMLY on the left side, some stuff launched. But note that the left app bar is also invisible, I clicked something at the top until user tab. I logged on as a guest in VM.
When in the Guest account, everything is OK, but it is very slow and the VM background REFRESHES(Flashes to black, then back to normal, then flashes to black again, back to normal again, in an infinite loop.) RANDOMLY, PLEASE, FIX IT.

Answer (score 2):

Enabling 3D acceleration fixed visual oddities for me.

You can find it in VM settings:
[image]

Comment: Do we need to set more video memory to the VM?

Comment: Enable 3D acceleration was what fixed it for me(or switching to Unity 2D)

Comment: I mean, it goes to a shell-less Desktop.

Comment: Clicking about randomly makes me think it's something I experienced a couple times where it just doesn't render, but I could be mistaken for your particular case.

Comment: is my host not support 3D? HP all in one 200 with core2 duo. if compatible, please tell me how to fix it, i experience that error WITH 3D acceleration of guest enabled, Ubuntu 3D. It don't happen in Ubuntu 2D. Please, i like the 3D, please tell me how to fix it.

Comment: please tell me how to fix it - FASTER!

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this:
Some things will render in the guest, but others will not.
Oddly, The little monitor display in the manager shows all of the components that are not shown inside of the virtual machine.

Hope this is helpful.

Zeddock